# Input shouldnt exceed xxx KB

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

im solving some questions in java and i come across this line in the question... " The total size of the input doesn't exceed 300 KB" , " The total size of the input doesn't exceed 256 KB"

my doubt is how can i make sure that my input is less than that value.

i actually tried using

```
CountingInputStream (CountingInputStream input = new CountingInputStream(System.in);)
```

to validate it. this is an external jar file by Google.

but when i submit my solution in the online compilers, `CountingInputStream` is not taken by the compiler. so how do i do it without using this ?.. in a general way ?

```
CountingInputStream input = new CountingInputStream(System.in);     
System.out.println("Enter Values: ");

while (scanner.hasNext() && input.getCount() < (256 * 1024))
```

this is now im doing ...but is there a way where i can control my input without using `CountingInputStream`. Kindly help

Comment: Where are these questions from?  Is it an on-line problem?

Comment: I think that means that it'll only accept a certain amount of input, not that you have to validate it. Could you give us more context for those sentences?

Comment: these are my college questions @markspace

Comment: so is it nothing i can do with my input ? but why is that this CountingInputStream used and told to me by my friends for this

Comment: I don't think we can really answer as to why your friends are telling you something. Maybe you should ask them that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own class that decorates an `InputStream`, overriding the `read` method to count bytes and then throw an exception when the number of bytes exceeds some threshold. Your driver could look like this:

```
InputStream in = new ByteLimiterInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.bin"));

while(...)
   in.read();
```

This will throw an exception when you've read too much data. It's up to you to write the `ByteLimiterInputStream` class. This is an academic exercise after all: exercise your own brain and don't ask others for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `InputStream`, call the `read()` method, and increment a counter.

`read()` will return a single byte, or -1 at end of stream.

e.g.

```
int MAX = 256 * 1024;
int count = 0;

while (true) {

  int return = is.read();
  if (return == -1) break;

  if (++count >= MAX) {
    // maximum limit reached
  } else {
    // store the byte somewhere, do something with it...
  }

}
```

Comment: this looks fine i guess.. i think int MAX = 256*1024 right?